# Using yahoo api with Oauth ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-services, api, yahoo

Everything's going well (using endpoints here http://developer.yahoo.com/oauth/guide/oauth-guide.html), getting an access_token.

Then it gets very confusing, let's say, just to identify the main user (wich domain ? - there are a lot in yahoo webservices) and then maybe access other services (read delicous, for example).

Why on earth is delicious giving explanations about connecting to it with oauth ( http://www.delicious.com/help/oauthapi) ?!!

Not experienced enough to know where to look at, to get a correct orientation to use it.
It is very confusing compared to the use of other webservices, if anyone has clues, experiences.

Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you seen YDN's Ruby Developer Center: http://developer.yahoo.com/ruby/

Comment: i did before asking. but nothing helpful for delicious.